# How to set packet color in NetAnim inside ns3

Tags: simulation, ns2, ddos, ns-3

```
AnimationInterface anim("DDoSim.xml");

ns3::AnimationInterface::SetConstantPosition(nodes.Get(0), 0, 0);
ns3::AnimationInterface::SetConstantPosition(nodes.Get(1), 10, 10);
ns3::AnimationInterface::SetConstantPosition(nodes.Get(2), 23, 10);
anim.UpdateNodeColor(nodes.Get(0), 0, 0, 255);

uint32_t x_pos = 0;
for (int l = 0; l < NUMBER_OF_BOTS; ++l)
{
    ns3::AnimationInterface::SetConstantPosition(botNodes.Get(l), x_pos++, 30);
}
```

[image: Simulation image]

By default all the packets in the simulation are shown in blue color.
I want the packet originating from node 0 in the simulation to be shown with different color than originating from botnodes, show that it can be easily seen which packets are from node0 and which are from botNodes.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can do so. You can only change the color of nodes, but not packets.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).